# pygame: custom classes inheriting from pygame.Surface

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pygame

I'm playing with pygame for the first time (and am kind of a newb about python in general), and wondering if anyone could help me with this...

I'm making a little shootem-up game and want to be able to create a class for bad guys. My thought was that the class should inherit from pygame.Surface, but that's giving me all kinds of problems (def, could be me screwing up basic inheritance/class stuff). For example, why doesn't this work(pygame, screen, etc all work fine and are used in other parts of the code, I'm just trying to move functions which I already have working into a class):

```
class Zombie(pygame.Surface):
  x_pos = y_pos = 0
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    #create zombie
    self = pygame.image.load('zombie_1.png')
    self = pygame.transform.scale(self,(50, 50))

    x_pos = x
    y_pos = y

zombie = Zombie(screen.get_width()/3, screen.get_height()/3)
screen.blit(zombie, (zombie.x_pos, zombie.y_pos))
```

The above produces an error: "pygame.error: display Surface quit"
edit: apparently this is a result of calling a Surface after pygame.display.quit() has been called. Anyone with any experience in pygame want to take a swing at this?

Entire code:

```
#Initialize
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

#classes
class Zombie(pygame.Surface):
  x_pos = y_pos = 0
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    #create zombie
    self = pygame.image.load('zombie_1.png')
    self = pygame.transform.scale(self,(50, 50))

    x_pos = x
    y_pos = y

  def is_hit(mouse_pos):
    #grab variables
    (mouseX, mouseY) = mouse_pos
    print "\nboxW_x, y = " + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + "\nmouseX, Y = " + str(mouseX) + ", " + str(mouseY) 
    headshot_x = self.x + (.5 * zombie.get_width())
    headshot_y = self.y + (.25 * zombie.get_height())
    margin_of_error_x = (zombie.get_width()/float(1000)) * zombie.get_width()
    margin_of_error_y = (zombie.get_height()/float(1000)) * zombie.get_height()
    print "Headshot_x: " + str(headshot_x) + ", " + str(headshot_y)
    print "diff in headshot and actual shot: " + str(mouseX - headshot_x) + ", " + str(mouseY - headshot_y)
    print "margin of error x = " + str(margin_of_error_x) + " y = " + str(margin_of_error_y)
    print "zombie size: " + str(zombie.get_size())

    valid_x = valid_y = False

    if abs(mouseX-headshot_x) < margin_of_error_x:
      valid_x = True
      print "valid x"
    if abs(mouseY-headshot_y) < margin_of_error_y:
      valid_y = True
      print "valid y"

    return (valid_x and valid_y)

#list of bad guys
zombie_list = []

#functions (which should later be moved into classes)
def is_hit():
  #grab variables
  (mouseX, mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  print "\nboxW_x, y = " + str(boxW_x) + ", " + str(boxW_y) + "\nmouseX, Y = " + str(mouseX) + ", " + str(mouseY) 
  headshot_x = boxW_x + (.5 * boxW.get_width())
  headshot_y = boxW_y + (.25 * boxW.get_height())
  margin_of_error_x = (boxW.get_width()/float(1000)) * boxW.get_width()
  margin_of_error_y = (boxW.get_height()/float(1000)) * boxW.get_height()
  print "Headshot_x: " + str(headshot_x) + ", " + str(headshot_y)
  print "diff in headshot and actual shot: " + str(mouseX - headshot_x) + ", " + str(mouseY - headshot_y)
  print "margin of error x = " + str(margin_of_error_x) + " y = " + str(margin_of_error_y)
  print "zombie size: " + str(boxW.get_size())

  valid_x = valid_y = False

  if abs(mouseX-headshot_x) < margin_of_error_x:
    valid_x = True
    print "valid x"
  if abs(mouseY-headshot_y) < margin_of_error_y:
    valid_y = True
    print "valid y"

  return (valid_x and valid_y)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)

#Display
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Massacre")

#Entities
#background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((0, 0, 0))

#make a zombie
boxW = pygame.image.load('zombie_1.png')
boxW = pygame.transform.scale(boxW,(50, 50))

#set up some box variables
boxW_x = screen.get_width()/3
boxW_y = screen.get_height()/3

#testing zombie class
zombie = Zombie(screen.get_width()/3, screen.get_height()/3)

#Action

#Assign
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keepGoing = True

#Loop
count = 0;
rotation_vect = 1.01
while keepGoing:

  #setup rotation_vect for this pass
  if (count % 3) == 0:
    rotation_vect = 0 - rotation_vect

  #Time
  clock.tick(30)

  #Events
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      keepGoing = False
    elif event.type is pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      #loop through zombie list, using each one's "is_hit()" function
      keepGoing = not(is_hit())

#Refresh screen
  screen.blit(background, (0,0))
  boxW = pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.image.load('zombie_1.png'), rotation_vect, 1.01)
  boxW = pygame.transform.scale(boxW,(count+50, count+100))
#for zombie in zombies
  screen.blit(boxW,(boxW_x+(boxW_x * .1), boxW_y+(boxW_y * .1)))
# error is result of following line
  screen.blit(zombie, (zombie.x_pos, zombie.y_pos))
  pygame.display.flip()

#increment count
  count += 1
```

Comment: For what it's worth, your `Zombie` class should probably derive from [pygame.Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) instead of `pygame.Surface`.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't call the inherited constructor:

```
class Zombie(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.Surface.__init__(self, size=(w,h))
```

And you're assigning to `self`. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question was asked one month ago, but maybe it's not too late...

What I see from your code is that you're basically trying to re-create the Sprite class.  Indeed, you are binding an image and a position together.

I did not understand what the gameplay was about (except for the head-shot part :D) but here's an example on how to display zombies and detect when they're being shot at:

```
import pygame

TITLE = "Zombie Massacre"
SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

class ZombieSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), image.get_size())
        self.defineHeadPos()

    def defineHeadPos(self):
        # To call each time the size of the rect changes.
        head_x_center = self.rect.width / 2
        head_y_center = self.rect.height / 4
        head_width = self.rect.height / 4
        head_height = self.rect.height / 4
        head_x_min = head_x_center - head_width / 2
        head_y_min = head_y_center - head_height / 2
        self.head_rect = pygame.Rect((head_x_min, head_y_min), 
                                     (head_width, head_height))

    def update(self):
        # Here we could move the zombie.
        pass

    def shoot(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        x -= self.rect.left
        y -= self.rect.top
        if self.head_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
            print "Head shot !"
        else:
            print "Shot."


def ActionShoot(zombies, pos):
    print "Shot at %s." % (pos,)
    sprites = zombies.get_sprites_at(pos)
    if not sprites:
        print "Missed."
        return
    sprite = sprites[-1]
    sprite.shoot(pos)


def DrawScene(screen, background, zombies):
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    zombies.draw(screen)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((32, 32, 32))

image_zombie = pygame.image.load('zombie.png')
image_zombie.convert()

zombies = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

zombie = ZombieSprite(image_zombie)
zombie.rect.move_ip(0, 0)
zombies.add(zombie)

zombie = ZombieSprite(image_zombie)
zombie.rect.move_ip(400, 100)
zombies.add(zombie)

zombie = ZombieSprite(image_zombie)
zombie.rect.move_ip(300, 250)
zombies.add(zombie)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)
    zombies.update()
    DrawScene(screen, background, zombies)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            ActionShoot(zombies, pygame.mouse.get_pos())

print "Quitting..."
pygame.quit()
```

It's not a complete game at all but I leave that up to you.  The key here is to use the sprites and the groups for displaying a bunch of zombies at different places.  You can put the 'intelligence' of the zombies in their update method (move them, zoom them if they get closer to the screen).  Note: I used only one image object for all the zombies.  If you start zooming, you want each zombie to have its own image object, that means loading zombie.png for each of them.  Otherwise when you zoom one they all zoom.